# JS variable from DOM chrome extension

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension

I would like to take some js variable using a injected script into the DOM. To do so I have two files the one that inject the script into the DOM and the one that send over the value.

getPageSource.js

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.src = chrome.extension.getURL('script.js');
    (document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
    s.onload = function() {
    s.parentNode.removeChild(s);
};

function getTag(){
    document.addEventListener('ITAG_connectExtension', function(e) {
    return e.detail;
});}

chrome.extension.sendMessage({
    action: "getSource",
    source: getTag()
});
```

script.js

```
var tagType = {};
tagType = itsClickPI;
setTimeout(function() {
    document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('ITAG_connectExtension', {
        detail: tagType
    }));
}, 0);
```

However the request.source in the popup.js is undefined.

popup.js

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender) {
  if (request.action == "getSource") {
    message.innerText = request.source;
  }
});
```

Could you give me some lights on here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am very, very curious where you got the sample messaging code. `chrome.extension.sendMessage` is _so_ deprecated [it ain't in the docs anymore](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=495052).

Comment: I took it from here: [link](http://solvedstack.com/questions/getting-the-source-html-of-the-current-page-from-chrome-extension). Should I update it for a new method?

Comment: Got it from your code :) thanks!

Comment: I'll edit it myself, thanks; you could instead [report the scraper site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/a-site-or-scraper-is-copying-content-from-stack-exchange-what-do-i-do) for violating attribution requirements (there is no visible indication content is from StackOverflow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with `getTag()` function - it is [asynchronous and cannot possibly return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) `e.detail`.

Even then the logic is suspect - you're adding an event listener, but you're triggering the event *before* it.

So what's the intended flow?

1. Get ready to receive a reply.
2. Inject a script that sends the data (that we are ready to receive).
3. Send that data somewhere else.

The correct chain of events would be this:

```
function sendTag(tag) {
  // chrome.extension.sendMessage / onMessage are deprecated!
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    action: "getSource",
    source: tag
  });
}

// 1. Get ready to listen
document.addEventListener('ITAG_connectExtension', function(e) {
  // This code executes asynchronously only when the event is received, so:
  // 3. Send the data
  sendTag(e.detail);
});

// 2. Inject the script
var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.src = chrome.extension.getURL('script.js');
    (document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
    s.onload = function() {
      s.parentNode.removeChild(s);
    };
```

If you need to do it several times, you only need to inject the script again (as the listener is ready).

Again, use `chrome.runtime.onMessage` on the receiving side.

Comment: That is supper, I guess it was an issue with the async type but I was not able to solve it. Thank you very much!